# PHP - Write a php code on a textarea, and show the result when the button is clicked

Tags: php

I'm trying to build an small script.

I have one textarea for the user's code and one submit button.

My target is when the user submit the button, the code that he wrote, must appear as a result, working.

I want to build a small php compiler, how can i do that?

```
Code
<form method="GET">
<textarea name="php">
<?php
echo '$texto';
?>
</textarea>
<input name="code" type="submit" />
</form>
<br>
<br>

Result
<br>
<?php
if (isset($_GET["code"])) {


echo $_GET["php"];
}
?>
```

Comment: have you heard of iframes?

Comment: There are couple of ways you can do this, 1. make use of `eval()` 2. Save code in php file and include that file into your application output screen 3. Save code in php file and use that as iFrame source URL.. Also it can sometimes be dangerous to run the code without identifying the bad points by the user, you shouldn't allow functions that can harm your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [eval() control structure](http://www.php.net/eval). However, please be aware that this is a *very dangerous* piece of code you're attempting to use. Basically you're allowing anyone to execute any type of code on the server. For example, someone could write "rm('file.php')" and basically get rid of your file. Or far worse things like stealing all passwords stored on the server.

```
<form method="GET">
<textarea name="php">
<?php
echo '$texto';
?>
</textarea>
<input name="code" type="submit" />
</form>
<br>
<br>

Result
<br>
<?php
if (isset($_GET["code"])) {
   echo eval($_GET["php"]);
}
?>
```

Again: PLEASE do not use this! It is *very* dangerous what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, btw, i dont want to put this code online, i just want to make some experiences